# Spring Data Redis (Jedis Lib) Connection Pool Utilization

Tags: redis, spring-data, jedis

We are using Redis for user-session info. for approx. 500 concurrent users with 430 req/s, we are getting Redis Implementation Layer (RedisTemplate) of 5 ms. we have configuration of Connection Pool Size 800.

Is there anyway we can measure no. of used connection / in-use connection / idle connection etc. (we use dropwizard metrics to report our data to graphite/grafana dashboard)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am curious. Are you configuring the Jedis connection pool while creating the JedisConnectionFactory? If so, could you post the snippet where the pool is being configured.